# Can PySerial watch for USB-to-Serial converter attach?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, usbserial

In my current implementation I have separate thread continuously looking for new ports by scanning

```
  from serial.tools import list_ports
  ports_avaiable = list(list_ports.comports())
  <some lines to check for new ports and sleep>
```

I wish to have solution like DiskDrive watch:

```
  import wmi
  c = wmi.WMI () 
  watcher = c.Win32_DiskDrive.watch_for(InterfaceType="USB")
```

but OS independent. I.e. sleeping until new converter inserted in USB port and my device appears in Serial port list.

Unfortunately I see no OS-independent solution after long search. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I would just use cygwin under windows and look under /dev/ for things like ttySX (where X is the serial port number)